# How to disable Resharper error with razor view "C# 7.0 language feature"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, resharper, c#-7.0

I have updated my MVC 5 solution to compile the razor allowing for c#7 features using `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider` however I still get these 'errors' all over from resharper that say "C# 7.0 language feature". See screenshot
[image]

I have tested and it all works. There's no actual errors when compiling and viewing the pages. Just these annoying warnings everywhere in VS. If I disable resharper they go away so seems linked to that. I also tried setting the C# language level to C# 7 on the .csproj and had no luck

Comment: If this goes away when you disable R#, then why not raise an issue on the [ReSharper Issue Tracker](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Issue+Tracker) and let the folk who wrote it provide you with an answer?

Comment: Good idea. I posted on their community forum as well

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in reSharper, it is failing to parse the langversion:default that is set in the compiler tag in your web.config. If you change the "default" to the desired integer then reSharper will pick that up. It will be fixed in reSharper 2017.2 when that is released.

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-465110 and the other stack overflow question linked from there.